# What should we do with answers without explanation?

Tags: discussion, answers

Today I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66625245/how-do-i-scrape-the-login-token-generated-by-js-in-python/66626158#66626158). There was already an answer providing working code, but without an explanation why this behavior is encountered. I do not know if the answerer just didn't bother to explain it, or did not *know* the reason. I *did* know the reason, and wrote another answer with an explanation. Then, I had a problem:

If the answerer *removes* his answer, no working code will be there anymore.

But I felt bad about simply copying his code, and I could not think of a better code.

Now my question is: Should I

1. copy his code while mentioning him as the author
2. edit his answer adding my explanation (where I would not get the reputation, though I invested time in it)
3. just leave the situation as it is now (code in one answer, explanation in the other), where the OP would have to choose between the answers, as you cannot accept two answers simultaneously. But he should to accept both, because one provided the solution, and one provided the explanation.

Comment: I would prefer 2. If that gets rolled-back do 1. Don't do 3.

Comment: I would go with option 4: write your own code into your own answer. Copying someones whole answer into your post while there are only those two answers is a really shady move, in my opinion. So write your own code and add it to the existing explanation.

Comment: @Tom "write your own code" - I wrote already in my question that I could not think of a better code

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure I agree with that. There may not be any reason to write new code when the code in the other answer is already sufficient. In fact, if one's own code is fairly similar to that in the other answer I'd say it would look shady if you wrote your "own" code without referring to the other answer. I think it's preferable to just correctly attribute the code in the other answer.

Comment: @Tom "Copying someones whole answer" - this was never my intention, I only thought of copying his code.

Comment: It was your intention, when the other answer is only code. So when you copy that, then you obviously copy the whole answer. *"I wrote already in my question that I could not think of a better code"* .. I read that and there's always another way of coding something especially when you incorporate with the existing explanation.

Comment: @Tom hm, okay, you may be right with that

Comment: Isn't one of the fundamental ideas behind SO that multiple editors can contribute to a simple answer?  Is it fundamentally true or fundamentally not that the original author of an answer "owns that answer"?  Just wondering.  I have no opinion.  I do think that the best answer purely from a "what's best for the question and the site" would be #2...to add an explanation to the existing code-only answer. - Sometimes you have to choose the good of the site over some extra reputation points.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL I would definitely say that's NOT a dup. Related, but not a dup.

Comment: @klutt exactly, I agree with you

Comment: I don't see "Ask the answerer to add an explanation in a comment" as an option. Personally, that's my first inclination. If the user does not add the explanation, then I might downvote the answer (I feel answers without explanation are not useful), add my own answer with (different) code and explanation, or just move on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Editing others answers

I would never make substantial edits an non-community answer if it can be solved by a comment where I ask the author to solve the issue themself. That's step one. Exceptions to this, is things like small errors and formatting and cosmetic stuff and such.

I very rarely edit others answers. It happens, but I really hesitate to do that. How likely I am to edit someone else answer depends on a variety of factors. Age is one of them. I'm more likely to edit an old answer. And I especially avoid editing answers that are less than 30 minutes, because it's really annoying to have your answer edited while you're still editing it. Another thing is how popular the answer is, and how many other answers there are. If a highly upvoted answer to a question with a lot of answers, is missing information, it's rarely any point in adding another answer. That were the reasoning when I added a TL;DR to [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/6699433)

#### Stealing code or not and how to do it if you do it

But in the majority of cases, I would not edit someone else answer to add a lengthy explanation. So lets go over to how you do with others code. It depends on the situation, but sometimes I have written answers like this:

> Others have already shown how it's done, but <explanation>
>
> And just for completeness, here is a working code example: <code>

But you could just as well post a link to that answer

I often cite the source when I copy code. It can be another answer or a completely different site. However, I usually don't do it when there's basically only one way to do it. Let's say that the question is "How do I error check malloc?", then I would not cite a source for a snippet like this:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof *p * size);
if(!p) 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

because this is pretty much how it's done. It's a real school book example. I would not blame anyone "stealing" a snippet like that anymore than I would blame anyone who "steals" a recipe for hard boiled eggs that says "Boil the eggs for 8 minutes".

Often when it comes to easy snippets like this, I just write the code from scratch. If it ends up almost identical to another answer, then so be it.

Also, remember that although working code examples can be good, they are not strictly needed. Especially not if the answer itself provides all information needed to construct such an example. Let's go back to my previous example with the question "How do I error check malloc?". I would say that this answer is good enough, even though a code example would make it better:

> Upon failure, malloc returns a NULL pointer. So whenever you have made a call to malloc and assigned it to a pointer, then compare the pointer to NULL. If it's NULL, then an error has occurred and you need to handle it. How you do it is up to you. One option is to simply exit the program.

#### Accepted answers

TBH, I would not really care if someone has to choose between two answers. It does not really matter. Actually, I prefer if people not use that feature at all. It's flawed. One single user should not have the power to pin an answer to the top.

Comment: Side note: I thought it was 10 minutes, not 8. (For a hard boiled one ;-)

Comment: @Scratte It was a guesstimate. I boil mine for 4 minutes. ;)

Comment: @Scratte lid on or lid off? I can recommend boiling with the lid on as it saves gas/electricity, but it does throw off the 8/10 minute rule. (I do 6 to get a yolk which is in that point of being solid but still a little moist - perfection).

Comment: @Gimby You can save even more energy by using the warm egg water for tea

Comment: @Gimby My recipe is: Add the eggs to the water while it's cold (this will prevent cracking of the eggs). Start the heat. When the water boils, set the timer to 10 minutes leaving the lid off. It'll give fully hard boiled eggs with no moisture in the middle ;) I haven't yet tried to perfect the process with the lid on. I'll have to get back to you with revised timing for that. I don't use the hot water for tea, as klutt does, but I do use it to boil other vegetables or for washing dishes :P

Comment: @Scratte Hard boiling eggs is worse than casting malloc

Comment: "I would never edit an non-community answer" then this [site may be not for *you*](/help/editing): If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

Comment: @Braiam Don't you agree with [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296691/6699433)?

Comment: @klutt with what? What has that anything to do with the blanket statement that you are doing? That post is about a very specific context, not a "I would never edit an non-community answer". So, lets go back at you. Don't you agree with [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199589/213575). (Note, it's also Servy that wrote that answer, and the edit was even more involved in that case).

Comment: @Braiam Did you miss the second part of the sentence? "if it can be solved by a comment where I ask the author to solve the issue themself." It's extremely rare that I don't try this approach first.

Comment: And it's still wrong! Don't you see it? This site is predicated on the basis that anyone is able to solve things without the author intervention, and the author should be happy about it. The help center explicitly tells editors should do it! **"Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!"** Your argument is the diametrical opposite of what the help center says, and that's enough to be absolutely in the wrong site. If you don't want to edit other post, don't do it. But don't discourage others to do it.

Comment: @Braiam This could turn into a lengthy discussion, but to put it short, I agree that's the way it should be. However, it isn't. If you handle others answers as a public wiki, many will react strongly, which would have negative effects for SO ass a whole.

Comment: Let the negative effects come. This site has strong wiki features, and if you are not happy about them, then just go where you are happy. Here, I like SE as a wiki, [like it was designed to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghvr8.png) And it was working that way before any of us came, and was successful then.

Comment: @Braiam Feel free to DV and post your own answer if you disagree

Comment: @Braiam You also argue to keep answerers happy, because they are the ones that make the site. You can't eat the cake and have it too.

Comment: @klutt don't know if you noticed, I closed this question as duplicate. I can't add an answer. And yes, I already downvoted it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like an idea to **add** code or explanations into the other answer.

Would it concerned my own answer, I would most likely roll-back any such edit unless this is a typo, grammar, or language **fixing**. While the editor could have good intentions:

1. The additional explanations could be **wrong**. Yes, simply wrong.
   I answer because I have some knowledge in the area,
   and that knowledge could be above the one of the editor.
   Why should wrong things be associated with my name?
2. The correctness of additional explanations could be **questionable**.
   I cannot say with evidence that given explanations are wrong.
   But I *feel* that something strange with it.
   Why should I mix the perfect code with the questionable explanations?
3. The additional explanations could be **lengthy**.
   I am looking into the original short answer of 4 lines.
   Then I am looking into 30 lines of additional explanations which are not very clear, but I cannot improve them...
   No, I am better leave my answer being short and simple.
4. I do **not want** to discuss the wrong approach proposed in the question.
   We visit Stack Overflow for find the best approach for our problem.
   And exactly that approach is described in my answer.

   Yes, in some cases it is really useful to explain why the wrong approach is wrong. But that explanations could perfectly be put into a **separate answer**.
   The "solution" answer for the ones who want to solve, the "explanation" answer for the ones who is curious.
5. And so on.

As you can see, there are many objective reasons to decline the other's edit for my answer. And these are not "hurt pride" sort of reasons, as noted in the comments. These are "I feel **responsibility** to maintain the answer in a good form".

---

Write your own answer. Ask yourself: "Would I be able to write a code **without** looking into the other answer?"

1. If yes, then **write your own code** for your answer. If possible, use your own variable names. If not.. let it be: It is perfectly possible that two persons could write very similar five lines of code independently.
2. If the other answer gives you **some ideas**, which you didn't know otherwise, feel free to use these ideas in the **code for your answer**, but with proper **attribution**.
3. If the other code is **completely new for you**... It is a rare situation (you have some understanding of the problem, but you have no ideas how to solve it), but it is possible. In that case you may write your answer **without the code**. If you found the other's code good, you could refer to it (but do not copy). In that case, possible deleting of the other answer doesn't harm your answer: The **explanation** of the problem is perfectly an answer.

Note, that the case 3 is not just about "I could not think of a better code". It is about "Without that answer I would never solve a problem in a such nice way".

Comment: "Never" seems a bit strong to me. So long as the answer is improved without changing the meaning, or the author's intent, that should be fine. Also, as someone who sees a lot of similar looking code, when I see code that is basically the same *apart* from variable names, that looks very fishy to me. There's nothing wrong with copying the code part of another answer to one's own answer if one doesn't have anything to add code-wise, so long as it's properly attributed of course.

Comment: @cigien: Ok, "never" was really bad, I have rephrased it. "So long as the answer is improved without changing the meaning..." - I would hardly imagine **adding** a code or explanations as "without changing the meaning": anything new actually **changes** a meaning and the author's intention. Well, the author of some answer may find useful some specific explanations, so he/she won't opposed from adding them. I have remembered the case when I actually rolled-back the edit which added more explanations into my own answer: those explanations was non-useful from my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Yes, I agree that adding explanations/code can be hard to do without changing the meaning, and is likely to be rare; its certainly not something that should be done frequently. However, I do believe that this can be done. And to clarify, in these cases, I agree that the author *does* have the right to rollback if they don't like the additions, as opposed to grammar and spelling fixes, which they're not supposed to rollback.

Comment: If hurt pride is a thing here, that could be resolved by disallowing the original poster to rollback any changes to his/her answer. Editing the answer would definitely be the right thing to do.

Comment: @Bachsau: There is no "pride" in rolling back the other's edit. This is just "I don't think that explanations are useful for my answer". They could be wrong explanations, they could be not good explanations from my opinion.. many possible reasons.

Comment: @Bachsau That would be a bad idea. My name stands on my answers, so I definitely want to be able to roll back things. What if the changes are wrong? Until my answer is a community answer, it's my answer.

Comment: @klutt Editors are shown by the answer, too. To me, an answer is like a wiki page, that everyone can and should improve, as long as that does not change the gist of it. SO is not like Facebook, where you post for reputation.

Comment: Yes, but editors are not nearly as visible as the author. Especially not those who are not the latest editor. I agree that rep is not that important, but still, if you edit another persons answer in a bad way, then they are the one that has to take the rep hit from downvotes. It's only a free wiki when it has become a community wiki answer. If there is an answer that you really think deserves being a community wiki you can flag it and explain this to a moderator.

Comment: @Bachsau Also, even if I agreed with you (I don't :) ) it does not really matter. Because many users here are very protective about their answers. And editing them like it was a wiki page will indeed cause strong emotional reactions. That's not good for anyone.

Comment: @Bachsau That being said, don't be afraid to correct things that are indisputably wrong and not is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Bachsau: I updated my answer with examples when additional explanations could be **objectively** rejected. "To me, an answer is like a wiki page" - Unless the answer's author *disassociates* him/her from the answer, the author has more control for the answer's content than others. Look: the author collects not only upvotes for the answer, but downvotes too. And the author's name is associated not only with the answer's advantages, but with disadvantages too.